# SQL*Plus TRIMOUT OFF Prevents Display Output

Tags: oracle, command-line, sqlplus, trim, dbms-output

In SQL*Plus, when I `set trimout off` the display output disappears.  This is unexpected.

Below is an example script that calls `dbms_output.put_line` once with `trimout on` and once with `trimout off`.

```sql
set serveroutput on size unlimited format wrapped
set trimout on
show trimout
show serveroutput
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(' hello world ');
end;
/

set trimout off
show trimout
show serveroutput
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(' hello world ');
end;
/
```

Below is the terminal output of the above example script.
Note: `hello world` is not displayed when `trimout` is `off`.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Mar 21 15:13:47 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.

SQL>set serveroutput on size unlimited format wrapped
SQL>set trimout on
SQL>show trimout
trimout ON
SQL>show serveroutput
serveroutput ON SIZE UNLIMITED FORMAT WRAPPED
SQL>begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line(' hello world ');
  3  end;
  4  /
 hello world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>set trimout off
SQL>show trimout
trimout OFF
SQL>show serveroutput
serveroutput ON SIZE UNLIMITED FORMAT WRAPPED
SQL>begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line(' hello world ');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I was expecting  `hello world` to be displayed when `trimout` is `off` as trimout controls

> "...trailing blanks at the end of each displayed line"

[SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-24581FCE-BF03-4707-A7E3-EB3E5ECC7EC8).

In both scenarios, the spool output shows the right trimmed  `hello word`.

> "TRIMOUT ON does not affect spooled output"

[SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-24581FCE-BF03-4707-A7E3-EB3E5ECC7EC8).

How does one use `trimout off` while still displaying output in the terminal?

Using Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not seeing that in the 19.4 full client on Linux